# Why is my JSON response from CodeIgniter not readable in JavaScript?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I store data in 'response' with CodeIgniter controller, which this:

```
{
  "ok": false,
  "messages": {
    "cgusrnm": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Full Name field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgnnm": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Nick Name field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgeml": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Email Address field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgunm": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The User Name field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgpsd": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Password field is required.<\/p>",
    "ccgpsd": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Confirm Password field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgcnm": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Company Name field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgadr": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The User Address field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgct": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The City field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgcnt": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Country field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgzn": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The State field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgzc": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Zip Code field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgpn": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Phone Number field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgsn": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Skype Name field is required.<\/p>",
    "pm": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Payment Method field is required.<\/p>",
    "cgpeml": "<p class=\"text-danger\">The Email Address field is required.<\/p>"
  }
}
```

But ajax file cannot read this array.

My ajax code:

```
$('#form_user').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var me = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url: me.attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    data: me.serialize(),
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.ok == true) {
        alert('response');
      } else {
        $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
          var element = $('#' + key);
          element.after(value);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's probably `response.data.ok`. `console.log` out the value of `response` and investigate its structure.

Comment: i flow this tutorial                https://youtu.be/H1sHOvc8au0

Comment: I'm not watching a YouTube tutorial to answer this question. Use `console.log` to look at what the value of `response` is. Adjust code accordingly.

Comment: i am not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the datatype is json, the type of the `response` variable is still string. Try adding `response = JSON.parse(response);` to convert the string to a JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: The reason is that you've called it `datatype` instead of `dataType`. `datatype` doesn't do anything. You could get rid of the `JSON.parse` and change it to `dataType`.

Answer (score 0):

message is not an array but an object. JSON arrays looks like {message:["a","b"]}

Comment: why can not work my code? i flow this tutorial        https://youtu.be/H1sHOvc8au0